# JQ raw text to double quoted key value pair

Tags: linux, shell, jq

I have this data.
{"bucket":"sdsd","key":"hghghg","region":"us-east-1"}
I want to convert it into following format. using shell commands.

- "bucekt"="sdsd"
- "key"="hghghg"
- "region"="us-east-1"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `to_entries` to access keys and values. To escape with quotes, it may not be sufficient to just put quotes around the names. Depending on your use case, converting to JSON strings using `@json` might be an option:

```bash
jq -r 'to_entries[] | @json "\(.key) = \(.value)"'
```

```json
"bucket" = "sdsd"
"key" = "hghghg"
"region" = "us-east-1"
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/qAoJ2Og7dqD)